# GalleryCMS - Uploadify - HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, upload, uploadify

I'm trying to upload files to GalleryCMS, but I get an HTTP error 500 each time.

I checked every webpage possible, I changed my php.ini, the execution time to 1200, the upload max to 300mb, I changed the sizelimit to 200MB, I tried to change modsecurity in the .htaccess file, the problem was not there.

I am able to upload any file upto 2MB, anything more I get HTTP error 500. Would any of you guys have any new ideas regarding this ? I got dead ends with most of the sites I visited.

Below is my uploadify script (it came along with GalleryCMS, I haven't changed it much, except for the size limit) :

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
'uploader'       : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>flash/uploadify.swf',
'script'         : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/api/upload/<?php echo $album->id; ?>',
'cancelImg'      : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/cancel.png',
'folder'         : '/uploads',
'auto'           : false,
'multi'          : true,
'scriptData'     : { 'user_id' : '<?php echo $user_id; ?>' },
'fileExt'        : '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
'fileDesc'       : 'Image files',
'sizeLimit'      : 209715200, // 200MB
'wmode'          : 'opaque',
'onSelect'       : function(event, ID, fileObj) {
  $('#upload-btn').show();
},
'onCancel'       : function(event, ID, fileObj) {
  $('#upload-btn').hide();
},
'onError'        : function(event, ID, fileObj, errorObj) {

},
'onComplete'     : function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
  var fileName = response;
  $('#upload-btn').hide();
  $('#new-images').show();
  $.ajax({
    url          : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/album/resize/<?php echo $album->id; ?>/' + response,
    type         : 'POST',
    cache        : false,
    success      : function(response) {
      if (response !== 'failure') {
        var new_image = '<li><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/' + response + '" /><br />' + response + '</li>';
        $('#new-image-list').append(new_image);
      } else {
        var fail_message = '<li>Thumbnail creation failed for: ' + fileObj.name + '</li>';
        $('#new-image-list').append(fail_message);
      }
    },
    error        : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert('Error occurred when generating thumbnails.');
    }
  });
}
});
```

To check it by yourself, the url is [GalleryMe](http://www.galleryme.co.cc)

> username: test@test.com
>
> password: 12345

Comment: What HTTP server do you use ? Could you check its logs ?

Comment: hey thanks for the fast response! I'm not sure if I am answering it correctly, but its HTTP/1.0 on linux server (ipage shared hosting). I was looking at the log files and weirdly I dont see the error from the file which was more than 2MB.

Comment: the link for phpinfo is http://galleryme.co.cc/php_info.php

Comment: This is because you were looking at the "access" log. Under Apache (the web server you use, not HTTP/1.0, HTTP/1.0 is the protocol), the "access" log is different than the "error" log. Can you get access to the "error" log ?

Comment: lol that makes sense... haha thanks still a newbie in many areas, let me try to find the error log and i'll get back to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using shared hosting, I am pretty sure you are experiencing a problem with your shared host configuration. As tells your phpinfo(); you are using Apache/2 with FastCGI.

I think that the MaxRequestLength of the FastCGI Apache module is set too low by your host provider.

If possible, you need to add this block to your VirtualHost config :

```
# Work around annoying fcgid limitations
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  # 20MB should be enough
  MaxRequestLen 20000000
</IfModule>
```

If not, you have either to contact your provider or to change provider.

Comment: i checked the error log.. and i see error caused due to resizing but nothing about 500 ErrorI guess i'll look for another CMS..

Comment: well before changing CMS you better make a simple test with a simple PHP upload form (no javascrpt, just a form with POST). I'm pretty sure  that error is not caused by the CMS but by the hosting infrastructure.

Comment: And, no, this block is not allowed inside the .htaccess file. You have to put it in your virtual host configuration.

Comment: hey sorry for the delay, i was out of town.. i do have another domain maintained by wordpress which allows 300mb of file upload since I had set the upload level to the same on php.ini in the same hosting service